# Is there a limit of alarms created by AlarmManager?

Tags: java, android

I am developing a school application, some functions require creating notifications and alarm clocks for the following cases:

- Option to add notifications or alarms to remember some school assignment, taking into account that the user can have multiple school assignments and create multiple alarms or notifications for each one
- Activation of an alarm clock for each day of the week
- Option to receive a notification a few minutes before starting each class

Currently I am storing the information of notifications and alarms in a database, I am using AlarmManager to schedule them and BroadcastReceiver to show them or reschedule them when restarting the device.

So far everything has worked fine but I don't want to start the production release because there is a high probability that users schedule a lot of notifications and alarms, I don't know if this could lead to problems such as not activated alarms or slowing down of the application, I don't want the user to have a bad experience with this feature

So my main questions are: Is there any limit or recommendation for the number of Alarms programmed by AlarmManager?, Is my approach correct?

Currently when adding the notification it is scheduled immediately with AlarmManager regardless of the date, but I have this other idea: Just store the notification information without scheduling it with AlarmManager until the day it should be triggered ... Would it be more convenient to create a only service with AlarmManager that runs, for example, every day at 03:00 am and to schedule notifications and alarms for the day?

I hope someone can help me, thank you very much